# How can I disable BULK API for my dev org?

Tags: bulk-api, permission-sets, organization-wide, bulk-permission

How can I disable BULK API access for my developer org? Do we have this toggle control at the org level? The use case here is I wish to detect BULK API behaviour in this scenario and make the integration fall back on REST APIs.

I know it is possible on the user level, using the API permission. The additional question to that is if this permission is turned off for the user, does this restrict only Bulk API or others also like SOAP and REST?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official doc :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000198725&type=1

**Manage Data Integrations - Allows the user to monitor or abort Bulk API jobs.**

Comment: As I understood from the document it is for an user. My question was mainly for an org level control, which if off, then even though user(s) has permission, won't be able to access BULK API. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: oh i am not sure how you would turn off bulk api at org level.  this is more at a profile level and not at an user level, so maybe create a profile and add all users to the same profile. (if possible based on your org structure)